.NET 8 Blazor - Page layout OnAfterRenderAsync life-cycle not triggered
Need some advice or guidance. I'm new at using .NET Blazor. I'm trying to configure a sort of auto logout function for my web app. The idea is to have it spin up as a timer when the web page loads and reset the timer each time a client interaction is detected.
The idea was to embed it into the main layout (I think it's statically rendered), but doing that does not allow me to use the OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender). The life-cycle event never fires. From what I understand, it's because that life-cycle event only fires for interactive components. So I cant really use that life-cycle event.
Problem I'm having, is that the JSRuntime can't be accessed if the page has not been completely rendered. I thought I could do a Task.Wait(), but that just seems like bad practice. Other life-cycle events throw a error due to the render state.
Update: Possibly found some documentation here (DOCS) Will need to test first.
CODE - MainLayout.razor
 public partial class MainLayout : IDisposable
 {
     private System.Timers.Timer? _timeoutTimer;

     [Inject]
     private IIdentityService? IdentityService { get; set; }

     [Inject]
     private IJSRuntime? JSRuntime { get; set; }


     protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
     {
         if (firstRender)
         {
             // set the timer to 5 minutes
             _timeoutTimer = new System.Timers.Timer((int)(1 * 60 * 1000));
             _timeoutTimer.Elapsed += TimeoutTimerElapsed;
             _timeoutTimer.AutoReset = false;

             await JSRuntime!.InvokeVoidAsync("timeOutCall", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
         }
     }

     [JSInvokable]
     public void TimerInterval()
     {
         if (_timeoutTimer is null)
             ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(_timeoutTimer, nameof(_timeoutTimer));

         // resetting the timer if the user is in an active state & restart the timer.
         _timeoutTimer.Stop();
         _timeoutTimer.Start();
     }

     private void TimeoutTimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
     {
         InvokeAsync(async () => await IdentityService!.LogoutAsync());
     }

     public void Dispose()
     {
         if (_timeoutTimer is not null)
             _timeoutTimer.Dispose();
     }
 }

Javascript - auth.js
function timeOutCall(dotnethelper) {
    var eventTypes = ['click', 'mousemove', 'keypress', 'scroll', 'touchstart', 'touchmove'];
    var timer;

    function resetTimeDelay() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () { dotnethelper.invokeMethodAsync("TimerInterval"); }, 1000); // Reset the timer after 1 second of inactivity
    }

    eventTypes.forEach(function (eventType) {
        document.addEventListener(eventType, resetTimeDelay);
    });

    // Remove event listeners when the component is unloaded or the timer is reset
    function removeListeners() {
        eventTypes.forEach(function (eventType) {
            document.removeEventListener(eventType, resetTimeDelay);
        });
    }

    // Return a function to remove event listeners
    return removeListeners;
}


"What a tangled web we weave".  Why not just set Interactivity to global?

make sure you have injected necessary services in  MainLayout.razor: @inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime @inject IIdentityService IdentityService, protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {      if (firstRender){                _dotNetObjRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);                _timeoutTimer = new System.Timers.Timer((int)(5 * 60 * 1000));                _timeoutTimer.Elapsed += TimeoutTimerElapsed;                _timeoutTimer.AutoReset = false;                await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("timeOutCall", _dotNetObjRef);            }        }

@MrCakaShaunCurtis Indeed... thanks for your reply. Will look into your suggestion and see what I can get going.

@JalpaPanchal, Yes, dependencies look to be fine. None of my required dependencies are null. The issue is primarily to do with the life-cycle method of the page layout component.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis, I don't believe page layout can be rendered in any other way, than static. Changing the interactivity mode on the layout to server, throws an exception.
InvalidOperationException: Cannot pass the parameter 'Body' to component 'MainLayout' with rendermode 'InteractiveServerRenderMode'. This is because the parameter is of the delegate type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment', which is arbitrary code and cannot be serialized.

you could try the below code

@JalpaPanchal, I reviewed the code and applied them. No luck, same outcome as my initial code. Seems the code you suggested had changes to the DotNetObjectReference and .
I think the main issue here is that the layout is rendered static, and can't be rendered interactively due to the "@Body" fragment. Static redered component/layouts never trigger the life-cycle event for "OnAfterRenderAsync".
I think my only option would be to create some sort of base component class, and apply it to all my component pages. If that's possible.

To set the interactivity to Global you need to set it in App.razor to Routes and HeadOutlet.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis you're a bloody genius. Thank you! I'm aware of my consequences below, but luckily I plan on making a fully server interactive app. So it's all good.

The caveat here is that you've effectively locked yourself into the render-mode permanently for all cascading components or rather the entire app.


Regarding your issue with the lifecycle method of the layout component not triggering as expected you could try this code:
You could create Interactive Component InteractiveComponent.razor:
@implements IDisposable

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject IIdentityService IdentityService

@code {
    private System.Timers.Timer? _timeoutTimer;
    private DotNetObjectReference<InteractiveComponent>? _dotNetObjRef;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            _dotNetObjRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
            // Set the timer to 5 minutes
            _timeoutTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(5 * 60 * 1000);
            _timeoutTimer.Elapsed += TimeoutTimerElapsed;
            _timeoutTimer.AutoReset = false;

            // Register the JS function to handle interaction events
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("timeOutCall", _dotNetObjRef);
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void TimerInterval()
    {
        if (_timeoutTimer is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_timeoutTimer));
        }

        // Resetting and restarting the timer if the user is active
        _timeoutTimer.Stop();
        _timeoutTimer.Start();
    }

    private async void TimeoutTimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        await InvokeAsync(async () => await IdentityService.LogoutAsync());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timeoutTimer?.Dispose();
        _dotNetObjRef?.Dispose();
    }
}

MainLayout.razor:
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<InteractiveComponent />

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

auth.js:
function timeOutCall(dotnethelper) {
    var eventTypes = ['click', 'mousemove', 'keypress', 'scroll', 'touchstart', 'touchmove'];
    var timer;

    function resetTimeDelay() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            dotnethelper.invokeMethodAsync("TimerInterval");
        }, 1000); // Adjust based on how frequently you want to reset
    }

    eventTypes.forEach(function (eventType) {
        document.addEventListener(eventType, resetTimeDelay);
    });

    // Clean up listeners when the component is disposed
    function removeListeners() {
        eventTypes.forEach(function (eventType) {
            document.removeEventListener(eventType, resetTimeDelay);
        });
    }

    return removeListeners;
}

Include this js file in _Host.cshtml

Code yields same issue as I have.
Layout is static by default. Layout can't be rendered interactively due to '@body' fragment and when rendered static, the OnAfterRenderAsync never triggers.

Thanks @MrC aka Shaun Curtis for assiting me with the issue.
Simply updating below components in App.razor, allowed me to render my page layout in "InteractiveServer" mode. Which then allowed me to use the page life-cycle I was trying to target.
Important to note: Caveat here is that you've effectively locked yourself into the render-mode permanently for all cascading components or rather the entire app
App.razor
<HeadOutlet @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

<Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

MainLayout.razor
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>

